# prompt for network setup during kickstart installation centos7

Tags: networking, centos-7, kickstart

I am trying to set the ip manually during kickstart installation using centos 7. During the installation it has to prompt for the network setup.

I tried using the below configuration :

`network --bootproto=static`

But this doesn't prompt for network setup

I Am aware that we can set it as `network --bootproto=static --ip=192.168.1.120` inside the kickstart file. But I do not want it that way.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the following configuration?

network --device=eth0 --bootproto=query

Hope this helps.

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work. Any other way ?

Comment: Sorry, this configuration only works in CentOS 5. In CentOS 6 and later, please follow the guide below:If you need to manually specify network settings during an otherwise-automated kickstart installation, do not use network. Instead, boot the system with the asknetwork option (refer to Section 32.10, “Starting a Kickstart Installation”), which will prompt anaconda to ask you for network settings rather than use the default settings. anaconda will ask this before fetching the kickstart file.

Comment: You will only be prompted for information about your network: 


 1.before fetching the kickstart file if you are using the asknetwork boot option 


2.when the network is first accessed once the kickstart file has been fetched, if the network was not used to fetch it and you have provided no kickstart network commands. 
Quota from:https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/s1-kickstart2-options.html

Answer (score 0):

If you need network before kickstart starts (meaning to download the actual kickstart file from the web/local network) and there is no DHCP server running anywhere. You need to specify the static IP on the kernel line.

Centos 6 has the option to put `asknetwork` on the kernel line, and it will prompt you to fill in network info.

Centos 7 does not have the `asknetwork` option during boot as this has been depreciated since the initrd image is now non-interactive.

To boot with a specific static IP on Centos 7, change the kernel line and add the IP information.

`ip=ip_address::gateway_address:netmask:fqdn_of_host:primary_ethernet_device:none dns=dns_server_ip`

Example

```
ip=192.168.91.92::192.168.91.2:255.255.255.0:centos.example.com:eth0:none dns=192.168.91.2
```

Remember if you need to configure the network adapter during kickstart to get installation to work you still need to add: `network --device=eth0 --bootproto=query` to your kickstart file.

> Note you have to specify the device you want this to happen on, its
>   not enough to just write `network bootproto=query`

That will prompt you for network information during the kickstart which is separate from the actual boot.

> Note: On Centos 7, if you want to use eth0 as your interface name you
>   also need to append `biosdevname=0 net.ifnames=0` to the kernel line.
>   Otherwise use the new interface naming scheme.